# Angular service for obtain pointguards (position === 1)

Tags: angularjs, filter, rxjs-observables

Currently i'm developing a web app which shows the Golden State Warriors (Basketball Team) Roster.

My main goal consists in filtering all players by position.

Positions are numbers ordered from 1 to 5.

My question would be: which could be the way to transform my http get request in order to obtain the point-guards (position === 1) ??

**roster-data.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from "../models/player";
import { environment } from "../../environments/environment";
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import {Observable, throwError} from 'rxjs';
import {catchError, map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class RosterDataService {

  private readonly devURL = environment.url;
  
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {
  }

  jSON_Server_ReadPointGuards():Observable<Player[]> {
    return this.http.get<Player[]>(`${this.devURL}/roster_GoldenStateWarriors`).pipe(
      map(players => players.filter((player:Player) => player.position === 1)
      ),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
  }
```

And then my interface

**player.ts**

```
export interface Player {

  fullName: string,
  shirtNumber: string,
  position: number,
  height: string,
  weight: number,
  points: number,
  rebounds: number,
  assists: number,
  blocks: number,
  steals: number,
  imageFile: string,
  imageDescrip: string
  
}
```

**players.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit, isDevMode } from '@angular/core';
import { RosterDataService } from "../../services/roster-data.service";
import { Player } from "../../models/player";
import { imgRoute } from "../../services/img-route.service";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-players',
  templateUrl: './players.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./players.component.scss'],
  providers: [RosterDataService]
})
export class PlayersComponent implements OnInit {
  public imageLocation:string;
  public bases!: Player[];
  public escoltas!: Player[];
  public aleros!: Player[];
  public alaPivots!: Player[];
  public pivots!: Player[];
  public getPlayers: Player[] = [];


  constructor(private _rosterDataService: RosterDataService) {
    this.imageLocation = imgRoute.path;
    
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.dev_SuscribeAllPointGuards();
    // this.dev_SuscribeAllShootingGuards();
    // this.dev_SuscribeAllSmallForwards();
    // this.dev_SuscribeAllPowerForwards();
    // this.dev_SuscribeAllCenters();
  }

  dev_SuscribeAllPointGuards(){
    this._rosterDataService.jSON_Server_ReadPointGuards().subscribe(
      pointguards => {
        this.bases = pointguards;
      }  
    );
  }
}
```

**players.component.html**

```
<section>
    <article>
        <h4 id="pointGuard">{{ "players.firstTitle" | translate }}</h4>
        <div class="gallery">
            <div [routerLink]="'/'+(base.fullName | removespaces)+'/'+base.shirtNumber"  *ngFor="let base of bases;">
                <figure><img src="{{imageLocation + base.imageFile}}" alt="{{base.imageDescrip}}" title="{{base.imageDescrip}}"></figure>
                <section>
                    <h5>{{base.fullName}}</h5>
                    <h6>{{base.shirtNumber}}</h6>
                    <h6>{{base.points}}</h6>
                    <h6>{{base.rebounds}}</h6>
                    <h6>{{base.assists}}</h6>
                    <h6>{{base.blocks}}</h6>
                    <h6>{{base.steals}}</h6>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: What exactly is your problem with this code? It looks fine from my point of view.

Comment: It doesn't show me the three pointguards. @FabianStrathaus, I've already edited my question by showing you the controller and view files to see if the rendering error is located there

Comment: You should add the response payload  you are retrieving from your API call. Does it matches your "Player" interface?

Comment: Thanks for asking me that question. In fact I already finally solve it! just by changing "Position" for "position" on API's (mocked JSON Server) attributes